# Django изменить наименование столбца в БД

Tags: python, django

Всем привет, кто подскажет как изменить поле **departament_id** чтоб показывало **имя** а не **pk** [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот **models.py**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    surname: str = models.CharField(max_length=60,
                                    verbose_name='Фамилия сотрудника',
                                    help_text='Введите фамилию сотрудника')
    name: str = models.CharField(max_length=60,
                                 verbose_name='Имя сотрудника',
                                 help_text='Введите имя сотрудника')

    department: str = models.ForeignKey('Department',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        verbose_name='Департамент')

    start_time: str = models.DateTimeField()

    end_time: str = models.DateTimeField()

    cause: str = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                                  verbose_name='Причина отсутствия',
                                  help_text='Введите причину отсутствия')

    scan_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='scans/%Y/%m/%d/',
                                   verbose_name='Скан документа',
                                   help_text='Вставьте изображение '
                                             'документа', blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.surname} '

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Ивент'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ивенты'
        ordering = ['-id']
```

вот **forms.py**

```
class AddIventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['department'].empty_label = "Департамент не выбран"

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['surname', 'name', 'department', 'start_time', 'end_time',
                  'cause']
        widgets = {
            'surname': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                              'placeholder': 'Введите '
                                                             'фамилию'}),
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                           'placeholder': 'Введите '
                                                          'Имя'}),
            "start_time": forms.DateInput(
                attrs={"type": "datetime-local", "class": "form-control"},
                format="%d-%m-%YT%H:%M", ),
            "end_time": forms.DateInput(
                attrs={"type": "datetime-local", "class": "form-control"},
                format="%d-%m-%YT%H:%M", ),
            'cause': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 10,
                                           'placeholder': 'Введите '
                                                          'Причину '
                                                          'отсутствия'}),

        }
```

Comment: Зачем? Это бессмысленно испортит базу

Comment: @andreymal, то есть все верно должно по pk? просто если делать в дальнейшем выгрузку в файл и брать данные из базы, то он же подставит только pk а не имя

Comment: 1) О какой выгрузке в файл речь? / 2) При чтении из базы вам ничего не мешает сходить в таблицу Department и прочитать имя оттуда